# libcodec and libcodec2-dev do not exist in Debian 8

Tags: apt, debian

I installed Debian 8 Jessie on a server and now want to install Freeswitch.
After `./configuration` command I went to `modules.conf` and enabled `mod_codec2`.
After that I ran `make`
While processing it said:

```
You must install `libcodec2-dev` to build `mod_codec2`.
```

Ok, and I googled and find out that `libcodec` should be installed first.
The command `sudo apt-get install libcodec2-dev returned:

```
Unable to locate package `libcodec2-dev`.
```

When I write `sudo apt-get install libcodec` in the terminal and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it does not display any suggestion.
I even installed `Synaptic Package Manager`, but still cannot find the package.

Can I installed it manually?
Or add somewhere in repository?
Any suggestion will appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can't find a Debian package, you can check http://packages.debian.org. I [searched](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libcodec2) for `libcodec2` there and saw that for Jessie, it is only in the [backports](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports) repository.

So, you need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and add:

```
# Backports repository
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then, update the list of packages and try installing `libcodec2` again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcodec2-dev
```

Comment: After i did what you said, it installed, or it seems to be installed! 
And now when i press make button again it says 
You must install `libcodec2-dev` to build `mod_codec2`.
How do you think about this?
I had a issue, something like this.
I had installed mysql , but terminal said i should installed,
After i installed php-mysql my problemm solved.
Is there anything like that?

Comment: @AlirezaAzadi I dont' really know. Please ask a new question, include the output of `dpkg -l | grep libcodec`, and explain the current error.